# ReSTful Flask file upload with request.stream

Tags: python, rest, file-upload, flask, wsgi

I am attempting to create a simple Flask endpoint for uploading files via `POST` or `PUT`. I want the `filename` in the URL, and then to (after the request headers) just stream the raw file data in the request.

I also need to be able to upload files slightly larger than 2GB, and I need to do this without storing the entire file in memory. At first, this seemed simple enough:

```
@application.route("/upload/<filename>", methods=['POST', 'PUT'])
def upload(filename):
    # Authorization and sanity checks skipped.

    filename = secure_filename(filename)
    fileFullPath = os.path.join(application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

    with open(fileFullPath, 'wb') as f:
        copyfileobj(request.stream, f)

    return jsonify({'filename': filename})
```

With a `multipart/formdata` upload, I can simply call `.save()` on the file.

However, any file I upload seems to have a different checksum (well, `sha256sum`, on the server then on the source). When uploading a standard text file, newlines seem to be getting stripped. Binary files seem to be getting mangled in other strange ways.

I am sending `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` when  uploading to try to make Flask treat all uploads as binary. Is `request.stream` (a proxy to `wsgi.input`) opened as non-binary? I can't seem to figure that out from the Flask code. How can I *stream* the request data, in raw binary format, to a file on disk?

I'm open to hacks; this is for a test project (so I'm also not interested in hearing how sending this as formdata would be better, or how this isn't a good way to upload files, etc.)

I am testing this via:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -H 'Authorization: ...' -X PUT --data @/path/to/test/file.name https://test.example.com/upload/file.name
```